# Add <li> to each element in jquery variable (before adding to UL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i'm trying to do

1. Bring in a selection of html elements from an external html (on the same domain) into a variable in jquery *(working)*
2. for each of the element items, wrap them  **(not working)**
3. prepend that variable to a ul in my page *(working)*

I have the following code that at this point, works, however it just dumps the elements (el) onto the page in one large list item, not each line on its own

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $div = $('<li>');

$div.load('pages.html .el', function(){
    $("#my-menu ul.toc").prepend($div);
});
});
```

I've tried a weird selection of wrapall, etc, but can't seem to crack this.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: where is your closing </li>?

Comment: [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) should work i.e. `$('#my-menu ul.toc').wrap('<li></li>')` should do I think.

Comment: use .before funtion.

Comment: Try this once `$('<li />').prependTo("#my-menu ul.toc").load('pages.html .el')`

Comment: What does .el contain in pages.html? Do you need to loop through items in .el to create multiple li's?

Comment: each .el contains
    <a class="el" href="signing-in.html" target="_self">Signing in</a>

Comment: AndrewR - at this point i'd settle for just taking each .el string and wrapping it in li's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the elements once they've been loaded from the external html. Something like this (untested code) might work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div = $('<div></div>');
    var $ul = $('#my-menu ul.toc');

    $div.load('pages.html .el', function(){
        $div.children().each(function() {
            $ul.prepend($('<li>' + $(this) + '</li>'));
        });
    });
});
```

If the `prepend` to the `ul` doesn't work in one line, it might work if you separate it:

```
var $li = $('<li></li>');
$li.html(this);
$ul.prepend($li);
```

Comment: Totally awesome , thank you! I had to seperate the prepend (and turns out I needed to change it to an append)... Thanks again.

Comment: Cool - you just confused me by accepting a different answer briefly :)

Comment: Yeh something happened with the page heh!

Answer (score 0):

I could not say anything without seeing the code, but you can try this one,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $div = $('<li>');

$div.load('pages.html .el', function(){
    $("#my-menu ul.toc").insertBefore($div);
});
});
```

Comment: that pretty much is that code i'm trying to get working

Answer (score 0):

Try and load the html in a hidden div..

```
$("<div id='pagesHtml' style='display: none;'></div>").appendTo("body");
$("#pagesHtml").load(pages.html);
```

..store the anchors in a variable..

```
var $anchors = $("#pagesHtml").find(".el");
```

..then make a LI for each anchor..

```
$.each($anchors, function(i, anchor){
    $("<li>" + anchor + "</li>").prependTo("#my-menu ul.toc");
});
```

..and then add that to your container.

If the order is wrong, then you should use ".appendTo" instead.

Happy coding =)

Comment: That seems close, but i'm getting the following error    Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in pages.html .el

each .el contains something like this <a class="el" href="signing-in.html" target="_self">Signing in</a>

Comment: I did get it to work with another solution thanks Repo, however, your answer may also help me do another part of the solution so i upvoted. Thanks